# Display PHP query result in textarea

Tags: php, textarea

I'm having a little problem over here, I'm trying to make a news system with an edit button, it's all going great but I'm having problems with the "textarea", I can display the results on inputs but when I try to display them in a textarea it wont, look:

This code works perfectly:

```
<input name="txt_02" size="87" maxlength="100" id="txt_Resumen" maxlength="140"  value="<?php echo $not_Resumen?>"/>
```

This wont:

```
<textarea name="txt_descripcion" cols="66" rows="10" id="txt_descripcion"  value="<?php echo $not_Contenido ?>">
</textarea>
```

I tried with $not_Resumen and other ones in the textarea and it doesn't work, the textarea would show up empty without the text, it should be a little mistake I'm making but I can't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just put it within `><`, there's [no value attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Example):

```
<textarea name="txt_descripcion" cols="66" rows="10" id="txt_descripcion"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($not_Contenido);?></textarea>
```

You should also use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) so that the textarea will not break if `$not_Contenido` contains `</textarea>`.

This is sometimes overlooked, but if `$not_Contenido` contained something like:

```
</textarea><script src="http://remotedomain.com/evilscript.js"></script>
```

An attacker can run anything they want, and all your clients will download and run the script on your website. A common attack would be sending cookies to their domain.

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
<textarea name="txt_descripcion" cols="66" rows="10" id="txt_descripcion">
     <?php echo $not_Contenido; ?>
</textarea>
```

We con't give value to the `textbox`.

Answer (score 2):

Value is not attribute  of textarea so simply place between the tag `<textarea>?</textarea>`

```
<textarea name="txt_descripcion" cols="66" rows="10" id="txt_descripcion" ><?php echo $not_Contenido ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Place your value between opening and closing tags of textarea as like other HTML tags and textarea has no attribute "value"

```
<textarea name="txt_descripcion" cols="66" rows="10" id="txt_descripcion"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($not_Contenido);?></textarea>
```