# Complete data not fetched

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to create an edit page for a particular row of my database. I am using ckeditor for one of my text field. The problem I am facing is, the data coming from database is incomplete for one field.

Comment: the code for testarea is:

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="content" value="<?php echo $row['content'];?>"></textarea>

while the result is coming from simple SELECT query.

Comment: Yes.. Although, the same code is running perfectly fine when i used it in another page. That means the data fetched in $row['content'] is correct but its not showing completely in the textarea.

Comment: Nope. Its longtext only.. otherwise it would have not even stored the complete text.

Comment: Yes.. but all of them compatible with the editor bcz the code stored is generated by the editor only..

Comment: Check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668213/display-php-query-result-in-textarea. And try to d what it stated.

Comment: Krishna please up-vote the answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code that you show. It seems that may be following problems are there:-

1. Either your column type is not long-text. So its not saving full data.
2. Either at the time of fetching data you are limiting character numbers.
3. Either your text is having some HTML code which is not showing in your ckeditor text-area.
4. Also value attribute is not there for textarea.So howto show then, please check link:- [Display PHP query result in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668213/display-php-query-result-in-textarea)

As we already discussed in chat that above three problems(1,2,3) is not there in your code. So check the link and i hope your problem will solved.

Comment: The problem was not in HTML code either. It was that, there is no value attribute for textarea. I got it from the given link.. Thanks for your help. :)